# Redirect to specific view if Pundit not authorized for show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, authorization, pundit

I have the following action for my proposals controller:

```
      def show
        @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
        authorize @proposal
      end
```

I have the following policy:

```
class ProposalPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :proposal
```

How can I redirect to a specific page. Say index proposals or root page if the permission is denied when trying to go to the show page?

When I navigate to it without the right permission I just get a rails error page with the following:

```
not allowed to show? this<proposal OBJ ispsum lorem>
```

I just want them to have a simple notification and redirected to another page. What is best way to do this? I am guessing with some sort of if statement in the show view but nothing has worked so far.

```
  def initialize(current_user, proposal)
    @current_user = current_user
    @proposal = proposal
  end

  def show?
    @proposal.published? or @proposal.proposer == @current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pundit has a mechanism for this.  You'll create a private method in your controller called `user_not_authorized` - in it you'll be able to create a flash notification and add a location.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

More information here: https://github.com/elabs/pundit#rescuing-a-denied-authorization-in-rails

Comment: Am I able to give custom messages depending on which action they are not authorized for?

Comment: Indeed.  Just add the policy and action to your locale file in config - you can see an example in pundit's documentation: https://github.com/elabs/pundit#creating-custom-error-messages